# Awesome CV: How to make \letteropening bigger? the line "Dear Mrs/Mr." etc

Tags: cv, awesome-cv

I can `\lettertitle` bigger via `\lettertitlestyle` but I can't find an equivalent for `\letteropening`

I would like to make the line bigger that starts `Dear Mr./Mrs` or whatever.

How is this possible?

The MWE takes the form of this overleaf template: https://www.overleaf.com/project/63a5c3cd5ff3997be97f9df6

`letteropening` appears in line 366.

How can I make the line `Dear Mr./Mrs Lastname` larger?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, we can't access your project. Really learn how to provide MWE with your questions if you really want replies. But I'll try to answer your request.

Second, I can't understad why on earth you want to do such thing.
Anyway, you can try to achive it by adding `relsize` package in your preamble.

```latex
\usepackage{relsize}
```

Then, in your document body, you can use `\textlarger{}` in your opening

```latex
\opening{\textlarger{Dear Mr./Mrs Lastname}}
```

Hope that helps.